# confused as to why my jumbotron is overlapping my div

Tags: html, css

Here's what it looks like on my screen, I am not too experienced but I am learning.

[image]

[image]

and here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Snakee06/pen/RqVKYX) for the code.

```
 <div class="heading" id="fquote"> 
<p>Get a free quote or call us today on 07375 200650</p> </div>
 <div class="heading" id= "os"> 
  <p>Our Services </p>
```

```
  <div class="services1">
    <h3 class="labels">Local Home Removals </h3>
      <a href="#"><img class="image20" src="images/ukmap.png"></a>
      <p class="label-text">A home visit will be carried out to estimate the cost of removal. This is a free service</p>    
  </div>


  <div class="services1">
    <h3 class="labels">National Home Removals </h3>
      <a href="#"><img class="image20" src="images/national.png"></a>
      <p class="label-text">A home visit will be carried out to estimate the 
         cost of removal. This is a free service</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="services1">
    <h3 class="labels">Packing</h3>
      <a href="#"><img class="image20" src="images/packing.png"></a>
      <p class="label-text">A home visit will be carried out to estimate the cost of removal. This is a free service</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="services1">
    <h3 class="labels">Dismantle & Assembly</h3>
      <a href="#"><img class="image20" src="images/dismantle.png"></a>
      <p class="label-text">A home visit will be carried out to estimate the cost of removal. This is a free service</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="services1">
    <h3 class="labels">Store Pickups</h3>
      <a href="#"><img class="image20" src="images/storepick.png"></a>
      <p class="label-text">A home visit will be carried out to estimate the cost of removal. This is a free service</p>    
  </div>

   <div class="services1">
    <h3 class="labels">Small storage solutions</h3>
      <a href="#"><img class="image20" src="images/storage.png"></a>
      <p class="label-text">A home visit will be carried out to estimate the cost of removal. This is a free service</p>    
  </div>
```

I have been trying to figure it out all night and not managed to, the only thing i can think of is i haven't closed a div but i have re-checked countless times added extra closing tags, moved in new div containers checked online but i dont really know what i am looking for.

Comment: Hey Chris, 

Happy to help, but we need to know which div is not acting properly. Unfortunately there is a lot of divs so it's difficult to differentiate.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi if you look on my codepen it is the <div class="jumbotron"> at the very bottom. It is overlapping the above div. It wouldnt let me post some of the code on here it said it was not formatted properly but it works on the codepen. I'm stumped

Answer (score 1):

This is an age old problem with CSS.

If a parent element contains nothing but floated elements, its height will be collapsed to nothing. It can be fixed by clearing the float after the floated elements in the container but before the close of the container.

Basically as your `.services1` divs are floated their parent div `.service1` has a height of zero. So in this case as your `.jumbotron` div element sits just under the `.container-fluid` div it gets overlapped by the row of `.services1` divs.

Your solution lies with clearing. If you .jumbotron div is to be empty you can get away with applying the following:

```
.jumbotron {
    clear: both;
}
```

However a better solution would be to apply a clear-fix to the parent of the floated elements. In this case `.container-fluid`. Add a reusable "clearfix" class to your parent element and the following to your CSS.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Since you appear to be using Bootstrap this should already be part of the framework.

Read more about clearfix here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Alternatives include applying `overflow: hidden;` to `.container-fluid` but this also hides any overflowing content, which may be undesirable behaviour in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Because the services are floating the container does not retain its height and everything seems to appear overlapping. Add overflow:hidden to the container.

```
.container-fluid {overflow: hidden;}
```

or give the div another class and set overflow:hidden for that class.

Answer (score 0):

It is overlapping because the "services1" elements are floats and a proper containing of floats is not been done.

Please find the the codepen with the solution: https://codepen.io/vishwaovi/pen/pQPeLZ?editors=1100

---

### What I have done is

1. Copy the clearfix code into CSS(last set of code in the codepen css)

```
.cf,.cf:before,.cf:after{
  content:"";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after{
  clear:both;
}

.cf{
  clear:both;
  *zoom:1;
}
```

2. assign clear fix to the parent of services1(Which is service1)

```
<div align="center" class="service1 cf">
```

(Also, I have added background color to jumbotron so it is visible. This you can remove it from the inline formatting)

Comment: This worked this and the information from this and others answers has helped me understand why thank you

Comment: Please accept an answer which seems appropriate. This will help the new people who will visit this question.